# Debug Assertion Error in C

Tags: c, debugging, assertion, decoder

got some code here that won't compile correctly because it is saying that my pointer is already null when i am testing for a not null expression in my main function. here is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXCODE        53
#define MAXMESSAGE    256

void getCode(char *codeIn, char *filename) {

FILE *codeFile;

/* Open the file with the code */
codeFile = fopen(filename, "r");

if (codeFile == NULL) {
    printf("Error opening the code file - program terminated\n");
    exit(1);
}

/* Read the first (and assumed only) line from the file */
fgets(codeIn, MAXCODE, codeFile);

/* Terminate the string with /0 */
codeIn[MAXCODE] = '\0';

/* Close the file */
fclose(codeFile);

return;
}

int getMessage(int *message, char *filename) {

FILE *messageFile;
int counter = 0;

/* Open the file with the message */
messageFile = fopen(filename, "r");

if (messageFile == NULL) {
    printf("Error opening the message file - program terminated\n");
    exit(1);
}

/* Read one number at a time from the file and store it */
while (!feof (messageFile))
{
    fscanf (messageFile, "%d", (message+counter));
    counter++;
}

/* Close the file */
fclose(messageFile);

return (counter);
}

void sortMessage(int *message, int size) {

int i, j, temp;
for (i=0; i<size-1; i++) {
    for (j=i; j<size; j++) {
        if (message[i]>message[j]) {
            temp = message[i];
            message[i] = message[j];
            message[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}

return;
}

void decodeMessage(char *codeIn, int *message, int size) {

FILE *outputFile;
int i = 0;

/* Open the output file */
outputFile = fopen("csis.txt", "w");

if (outputFile == NULL) {
    printf("Error opening the output file - program terminated\n");
    exit(1);
}

for (i=0; i< size; i++) {
    fprintf(outputFile, "%c", codeIn[message[i]%100]);
    printf("%c", codeIn[message[i]%100]);
}
printf("\n");

/* Close the file */
fclose(outputFile);

return;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
  char code[MAXCODE];
  int msg[MAXMESSAGE];
  int msgSize;

if (argc != 3) {
    printf("This program takes two arguments: the name of the file with the code, and the name of the file with the encoded message\n");
}

getCode(code, argv[1]);
msgSize = getMessage(msg, argv[2]);
sortMessage(msg, msgSize);
decodeMessage(code, msg, msgSize);


return;
}
```

So basically my code is using two files called codefile.txt and msgfile.txt to decode the secret message and write the decoded sequence to a new text file called csis.

Comment: What's the error message you get?

Comment: `/* Terminate the string with /0 */`
`codeIn[MAXCODE] = '\0';`

That's an error.  You're array is not that large.

Comment: Imagine how inefficient the world of information technology would be if we all reinvented the wheel every time we needed to do simple things like sort an array, rather than using the standard library `qsort`...

Comment: thanks for the input, i haven't learned that function yet

Comment: @woolstar the expression: file_name != nullptr

Comment: Do not vandalize your question after you have an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As woolstar pointed out in the comments, you don't need to NUL terminate your `codeIn` array following `fgets`, because `fgets` will do that for you. In fact, this constitutes an overflow which we can best see by considering what happens when `MAXCODE` is 1: `codeIn` contains only one element: `codeIn[0]`, and accessing `codeIn[1]` is an error.

Similarly, since `MAXCODE` is `53` and that's how many elements pointed to by `codeIn`, `codeIn[message[i]%100]` is suspicious because there's a potential for `message[i]%100` to be an invalid index. While we're on this note, it might be wise to make `message[i]` an `unsigned int` so that it can't be negative. The format specifier (for `printf` and `scanf`) corresponding to `unsigned int` is `%u`.

`while ( !feof(messageFile) )` is wrong because the `EOF` flag isn't set until an attempt is made at reading. Between attempting to read and your `EOF` test, however, you've incremented `counter` which means you've counted one too many items. Perhaps your loop should look like this:

```
while (fscanf(messageFile, "%d", (message+counter)) == 1)
{
    counter++;
}
```

Note that this code assumes you've chosen to keep `message[i]` as an `int`. If you've chosen to use `unsigned int` instead, of course you'll want to use the `%u` format specifier.

You can probably see that `feof` is mostly superfluous... You can usually test for erroneous reads by checking the return value. Try to avoid `feof` in the future.

Your `main` function has a return type of `int`, yet at the end of it you have a `return;` statement which doesn't return an `int` value. Remove that. It's probably causing errors during compilation.

Presumably, when `argv != 3` you want to return from `main` so you don't end up processing invalid arguments... Make sure you return an `int` value, e.g.

```
if (argc != 3) {
    printf("This program takes two arguments: the name of the file with the code, and the name of the file with the encoded message\n");
    return 0;
}
```